Android Studio's Emulator stops responding on every click
I have recently moved to Nobara Linux from Windows. The only thing holding me to the latter right now is my problem with Android Studio.
I use the Android Virtual Device feature to check out new functions and test things.
The problem is after I downloaded the official archive and set up things, the emulator windows says "Emulator" stopped responding on every mouse click, and after I press "Wait" and not close i can use it until next mouse click.
I have tested release version of Android Studio, canary and near release, all to no avail. Tested different APIs - no go.
I am happy to provide any information but keep in mind I am not experienced in Linux.
Neither official archives nor Flatpak version works. It always freezes on mouse click.
Neofetch output:
OS: Nobara Linux 40 (GNOME Edition) x86_64
Kernel: 6.10.3-201.fsync.fc40.x86_64
Packages: 3070 (rpm), 10 (flatpak)
Shell: bash 5.2.26
Resolution: 1920x1080
DE: GNOME 46.4
WM: Mutter
WM Theme: Adwaita
Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3]
Icons: Adwaita [GTK2/3]
Terminal: gnome-terminal
CPU: Intel Xeon E3-1230L v3 (8) @ 2.800GHz
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X
Memory: 3834MiB / 23902MiB

Configure hardware acceleration for the Android Emulator.

The emulator runs best if it can use your machine’s hardware, such as
the CPU, GPU, and modem, rather than running as pure software. The
ability to use your machine’s hardware to improve performance is
called hardware acceleration.
The emulator can use hardware acceleration to improve your experience
in two main ways:

Graphics acceleration for improved screen rendering Virtual machine
(VM) acceleration for improved execution speed


About hypervisors:

VM acceleration requires a hypervisor, a tool that uses virtualization
extensions provided by your computer's processor.
Without a hypervisor and VM acceleration, the emulator must translate
the machine code from the VM block by block to conform to the
architecture of the host computer. This process can be quite slow.
With a hypervisor, when the VM and the architecture of the host
computer match, the emulator can run code directly on the host
processor using the hypervisor. This improvement drastically increases
both the speed and performance of the emulator.

Cradit: -- Configure hardware acceleration for the Android Emulator.
Now I am saying from my own experience:
The hardware specification of my PC was bad enough. On that PC I used to do some extras with following the link given above while running the emulator.
For example:

Always select x86 image over x64,
Enable the 'Disable Animation' option of the emulator from Accessibility,
From the Developer Options, enable the 'Dont keep activities' option, And
disable all unnecessary system apps that run in the background.

Thus I used to use the emulator on my old nearly dead PC, and without lag I could use the emulator.

Provide pc specification and operating system version.
Possibly its software glitch. Once you provided those information I might able to provide troubleshooting steps on how to resolve that issue.

I added neofetch output.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

better opening avd manager.
then change the advanced settings to cold boot,close the emulator and run once again.

Doesn't matter if I cold boot or quick boot its all the same.
